# Split file and turn it into dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, split

```
counts = dict()

for word in x:                                  # x is file named "f2.txt"
    words = word.split()
    print words
    counts[words] = counts.get(words,0) + 1
print counts
```

I want to split a file and then want to print the words which is used maximum times.

But I am not even able to create dictionary, above code prints empty dictionary `{}`.

---

P.S. I have not added 1st part of the code, which is for opening file, counting total number of lines and for printing all lines in uppercase.

Comment: You have to open the file with `open` function.

Comment: @thefourtheye Please see the P.S. part. I have not mentioned that because  I don't think it is need. Though if you want I can add it :)

Comment: how is the input file ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. It is simple `.txt` file. I have mentioned that in the code. check second line comment. :)

Comment: better to use `Counter` of `collections`

Comment: what expected with: words ? .... `words` isn't using

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. I was trying to see whether it splits the file or not. So i have used `print words`. It does not print anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter()` which takes a text as input and returns a dictionary recording the frequency of each word in the file.

**sample.txt:**

```
hello this file is good
file is is good excellent
```

And the code for reading and recording the frequency of words:

```
import collections
with open("sample.txt", "r") as datafile:
    lines = datafile.read()
    words = lines.split()
    words_hist = collections.Counter(words)
    print words_hist
```

Output:

```
{'is': 3, 'good': 2, 'file': 2, 'this': 1, 'excellent': 1, 'hello': 1}
```

As per your posted solution, It seems that, you are incorrectly reading the input file. So I have edited your approach a bit:

```
counts = dict()

with open("sample.txt", "r") as datafile:
    x = datafile.read().split()
    for word in x:                               
        words = word.split()
        print words
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1
print counts
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I have not learned all that yet but I can understand it. :) Though I can see downvotes as usual :(

Comment: Ignore those downvotes. keep practising, Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You asked about most common word.I've shown three most common words.

```
 In [102]: line
    Out[102]: ' Mom   can   I    have  an  ice cream?Mom I Mom Mom'

    In [103]: li=line.split()

    In [104]: li
    Out[104]: ['Mom', 'can', 'I', 'have', 'an', 'ice', 'cream?Mom', 'I', 'Mom', 'Mom']

    In [105]: collections.Counter(li)
    Out[105]: Counter({'Mom': 3, 'I': 2, 'ice': 1, 'an': 1, 'can': 1, 'have': 1, 'cream?Mom': 1})

    In [106]: collections.Counter(li).most_common(3)
    Out[106]: [('Mom', 3), ('I', 2), ('ice', 1)]
```